# Can a weak entity type be involved in an "is-a" relationship?

Tags: database-design, erd, subtypes

Considering the scenario depicted in the diagram below, as the title says, can a weak entity type take part in an "is-a" relationship?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When I've modeled databases, I would use a `isType` description where you have `isA`.  You appear to have two types of `Specs`; `labelSpecs` and `itemSpecs`.  Common data belongs in `Specs` entity, with type specific data in the appropriate subtype record.  Normally subtypes are exclusive, so a Spec would be either a `labelSpec` or an `itemSpec`.